# Selecting the substring with the highest count in a column where the substrings are separated with spaces

Tags: sqlite, select, count

How do I select the most frequent word in a column in which words are separated by spaces? I'm using SQLite as a database.

For example,

```
Column1  Column2
1        Apple Orange Banana
2        Strawberry Apple Pineapple
3        Grape Mango
```

Desired output: Apple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Word counting.** Suppose your table is called yourTable. Use a common table expression (with clause) to split Column2 into separate words. I borrowed some knowledge from user1461607 and came up with this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE split(word, str, hasspace) AS (
SELECT '', Column2, 1 from yourTable 
UNION ALL SELECT
substr(str, 0, 
    case when instr(str, ' ')
    then instr(str, ' ')
    else length(str)+1 end),
ltrim(substr(str, instr(str, ' ')), ' '),
instr(str, ' ')
FROM split
WHERE hasspace
)
SELECT trim(word) FROM split WHERE word!='' GROUP BY trim(word) ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This works perfectly, ignoring the "Unable to parse query text' warning in the Query Builder. Thanks. But, Visual Studio's query builder keeps rearranging the query when I open its query builder again, but I can always just paste the original query somewhere and paste it back in the query builder. If anyone knows how to prevent this though, I would be thankful if you post how.